# Deallocating vector of primitives

Tags: c++, stl

I'm digging through some ancient code, originally built in C++ Builder 6. Littered through-out the code base is the following pattern, which, IMHO, segfaults as it should:

```
vector<int> x;
try {
    ... some run of the mill vector manipulation
} __finally {
      delete &x;
}
```

The `delete &x;` is really odd. As I understand it, the `vector<int>` will only exist for the lifetime of the function it is contained within, so no need to call `delete` on it.

Is there some sensible motivation behind this pattern, or is it just plain wrong?

Comment: I don't know about 'wrong', if your aim is to write good code this is awful, but if your aim is to frustrate people 10 years down the line trying to maintain your code this is perfect, ideal, fantastic!

Comment: Point taken... I can't imagine why this did not cause problems years ago.

Comment: ... fact is, it probably *did.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly not standard C++.

A `delete` should only be used if `new` is used. Else the behaviour is *undefined*.

Answer (score 2):

At least as you've shown it here, it's just plain wrong.